# How do I Switch JPanels inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Quite green regarding javas component-stuff etc so please excuse me if information given by me isn't enough!

Considet the code below. Adding menu and menu showing in frame, no problem.
I want when gameOn() is called to remove the menu and instead start the game.
The code below only makes the Frames surface "blank", no gamepanel added.

Any thoughts/suggestions on how to fix it? The MenuPanel has a mouselistener.

```
public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

private MenuPanel mp; //extends JPanel
private GamePanel gp; //extends JPanel

public GameFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(GameFrame.XSIZE, GameFrame.YSIZE));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    mp = new MenuPanel(this);

    add(mp);
}
public void gameOn() {
    remove(mp);
    GamePanel gp = new GamePanel(5);
    add(gp);
}
}
```

Comment: Try to make a "repaint();" after add(gp);

Comment: try to call pack(); after adding the panel!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to add an remove components, use a `CardLayout`

```
CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

MenuPanel menu = new MenuPanel();
GamePanel game = new GamePanel();
mainPanel.add(menu, "menu");
mainPanel.add(game, "game");

...
public void gameOn() {
    cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "game");
}
```

When `gameOn()` is called, the `menu` will get pushed to the back, and the `game` to the front.

This way you don't have to keep adding and removing

**Here's an example you can run**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    CardLayout cardLayout;
    JPanel mainPanel;
    MenuPanel menu;
    GamePanel game;

    public GameFrame() {
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        mainPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        menu = new MenuPanel();
        game = new GamePanel();
        mainPanel.add(menu, "menu");
        mainPanel.add(game, "game");


        JButton goGame = new JButton("Go TO Game");
        goGame.addActionListener(this);

        add(mainPanel);
        add(goGame, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        gameOn();
    }

    public void gameOn() {
        cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "game");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GameFrame gameFrame = new GameFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MenuPanel extends JPanel {

    public MenuPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        add(new JLabel("Menu"));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    public GamePanel() {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        add(new JLabel("Game"));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After adding the GamePanel, do `validate();`

```
public void gameOn() {
remove(mp);
gp = new GamePanel(5);
add(gp);
validate();
```

}

Comment: Nice, that worked! But, when done it my keyListener in GamePanel seems to be not working after doing so. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Add the GamePanel class in your first post to see what's wrong.

Comment: Foudn another question regarding that matter, should have checked it first sry! after validate(); I called
gp.requestFocusInWindow()
and it worked. Thx for the help!

Comment: No problem. Hope you won't get any others problems.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `repaint()` after you remove one panel and add another, `setVisible(true)` should be done after you've added your componen
ts to the frame and I recommend doing heavy UI changes like that on the EDT thread to avoid interference.

Comment: repaint() makes no difference. Sorry, Im quite unfamiliar with threads  at this moment.