# Add panel to a panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

i'm building a Java program. The core of this program is visualized in a JFrame with a JMenuBar and various JMenuItem and JMenu. The point is that I added a centralPanel to all the frame,but if I add something to the centralPanel it shows only if i resize the main frame, reducing it or enlarging it!
Here's the code:

This is the constructor:

```
    public UserFrame(Sistema system)
    {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    storicoPanel = new JPanel();
    carrelloPanel = new JPanel();
    carrelloFrame = new JFrame();
    pane = new JScrollPane(storicoArea);
    close = new JButton("Chiudi");
    this.sistema = system;
    menu = new JMenuBar();
    this.setJMenuBar(menu);

    centralPanel = new JPanel();
    add(centralPanel);
```

Here i added the centralPanel, and here, in an ActionListener, i try to add something to it, but it doesnt' work:

```
public ActionListener createVisualizzaStorico(final ArrayList<Acquisto> array)
{
    class Visualize implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        storicoPanel.removeAll();
        for(Acquisto a : array)
        {
            Articolo temp = a.getArticolo();
            if(temp instanceof Vacanza)
                storicoPanel.add(new VacanzaPanel((Vacanza)temp));
            else if(temp instanceof BeneDiConsumo)
                storicoPanel.add(new BeneDiConsumoPanel((BeneDiConsumo)temp));
            else if(temp instanceof Cena)
                storicoPanel.add(new CenaPanel((Cena)temp));
            else 
                storicoPanel.add(new PrestazioniOperaPanel((PrestazioneOpera)temp));

        }

        centralPanel.add(storicoPanel);
        centralPanel.repaint();
```

Could you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Have you attached the action listener?

Comment: want to replace panel with another panel??

Comment: Are you using SwingUtilities.invokeLater()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CardLayout` instead of trying to add and remove component/panels. It's much cleaner and you don't have to worry about the things that may go wrong, like what you're facing here.

See [**this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435) to see how easy and cleaner it is. Also see [**How to Use CardLayout**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) tutorial

---

**Side Notes**

- A component can only have one parent container. Though I don't think this is causing a problem for you. It's good to know. First I see you trying to add `storicoPanel` to a `JScrollPane`,  `JScrollPane` that you never add to the `centerPanel`. Then you later add the `storicoPanel` to the `centerPanel`. The `JScrollPane` will no longer be the parent after this.
- I'm not sure what you're using this `carrelloFrame = new JFrame();` for, but you're class is already a `JFrame`, why create another?
- Just FYI, when adding components dynamically, you need to `revalidate()` *and* `repaint()`. Though, in your situation, I am totally against the adding and removing of components, because this looks like a perfect case for a `CardLayout`.

Comment: Oh my! Thanks a lot, you just saved me! Don't bother about the new frames, I used them to test and to see if it was my fault or JPanel's fault! CardLayout is wonderful, thanks again!

Comment: For the record, `revalidate()` is what you needed here. It should work calling them both together (as `revalidate()` is required if you're dynamically modifying the component hierarchy). That said, `setVisible(false), repaint(), setVisible(true)` has worked for me historically :)

Answer (score 0):

Try these..

```
centralPanel.updateUI(); // or    
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
```

---

1. Execute your frame code in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`
2. Instead of `repaint()` call `updateUI()` or
   `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane())` to update the
   user interface.