# Java Update JPanel components WITHOUT removing

Tags: java, jpanel

I have a complex JPanel, that has various nested JPanels as components.

I want to replace one of these nested panels with a new one. But I can't get Top-Level Panel to redraw with new components unless I delete and add them all again:

```
JPanel topLevel = new JPanel();
JPanel upperPane = new JPanel();
JPanel lowerPane = new JPanel();

JPanel infoPane = new JPanel();

upperPanel.add(infoPane);
topLevel.add(UpperPane);
topLevel.add(lowerPane);
```

// The above (psuedocode) display nicely.
//Now I want to:

```
infoPane = new JPanel(); //Changed this Panel somehow;

topLevel.revalidate();
topLevel.repaint();
```

//The above 2 lines do NOT display the new information.

How can I get it to update?

Comment: _"How can I get it to update?"_ Use a `CardLayout` instead of trying to _replace_. See [**this example**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet That does not do what I need as all "cards" need to be created at start. You cannot change the underlying card AFTER you have displayed the first one.

Comment: Consider posting a [MCTRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling `new JPanel()` then you are referencing a different point in memory. Therefore, the reference to the old `JPanel` on `upperPanel` is lost, and changes made to `infoPane` after this will not be shown.

Haven't tried it myself, but change infoPane without calling `new` and that may well be your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as I am using library that forces me to do a new to get a Chart.

Comment: Then simply repeat `upperPanel.add(infoPane);`. When you call `new` then you are no longer referring to the `JPanel` that is shown, so any changes made will be invisible until you add it.

Comment: BUT. I would need to remove it from upperPanel first. The problem is that I get Screen Glitches sometimes between removing and adding again - even if they are consecutive lines

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the design paradigm you describe seems awkward to me.  Wouldn't it be more straightforward to continue with that original infoPane instance and simply redraw its contents?  Then your topLevel panel doesn't have to be involved with the change.

So, have your infoPane display whatever it is that your library gives you when you call new(), and just use new() to put  new WhateverItIs() inside your infoPane.

Would that work in your context?

Hope this helps.

Comment: That would be wat I want - but unfortunately if use use "new"anywhere lower down in the nesting, the higher level panels do not recognise the change.