# Running Applet Out of JButton

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have a Applet game, and it consists of a Applet class for the game, and a regular `drawpanel` class for the graphics. I wanted to use a third class to have a main menu, that had several `JButton`s to direct to other class I want to make, but more importantly to open the `Applet` game class. Does the `Menu` Class have to be an `Applet`? I wouldn't think it would, but if not, how could I use a line of code similar to

Pacman g = new Pacman();

To open a Applet class?

Thank You!

(I don't have many years of programming under my belt, as I am just a tenth grade student in AP Computer Science)

Answer (score 2):

> "Does the Menu Class have to be an Applet?"

No, just use a `CardLayout`. Put another `JPanel` class in the `Applet` class. So you have your `DrawPanel` and `MenuPanel`. See [**How to Use CardLayout**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

```
public class MyApplet extends JApplet {
    DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
    MenuPanel menuPanel = new MenuPanel();

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    }

    class MenuPanel extends JPanel {
    }
}
```

See the running example from [**How do I Switch JPanels inside a JFrame**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435) for a simple implementation of `CardLayout`. The basic concept is to *layer* the `JPanel` on top of one another. And you can use a button click to show a different panel. So you would start with with `MenuPanel`, then a button on that panel can cause the `CardLayout` to show the `DrawPanel`

---

**Side Note**

- Have a look at [**Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets**](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) and suggest it as a good read for your teacher :)
- Use Java naming convention. Clas names begin with capital letters using camel casing, e.g. `DrawPanel` and not `drawpanel`