# What is a proper update() method for my GUI (JAVA)

Tags: java, user-interface

Im displaying a 8x8 grid of pictures for a new game and these pictures are places randomly using a two dimensional array and math.random()

There is also a "new game" button I want the user to be able to refresh the page without opening a new GUI [image]and re displaying the grid aswell.

This is my method for displaying the grid

```
for (int r = 0; r < ShinyButtons.ROWS; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < ShinyButtons.ROWS; c++) {

              newbuttonTable[r][c] =  new JButton(icons[(int) (Math.random()*7)]);
              newbuttonTable[r][c].setLocation(10+c*69, 10+r*69);
              newbuttonTable[r][c].setSize(69, 69);
              add(newbuttonTable[r][c]);


    }
```

Comment: Consider using a `GridLayout(...)` instead of manually placing the buttons with `setBounds`. Apart from that: You can remove all buttons from this panel by calling `removeAll()` (but am not sure whether this is what you are asking for)

Answer (score 0):

> "I want the user to be able to refresh the page without opening a new GUI"

You should use a `CardLayout` for this functionality. You can *"stack"* panels and navigate through them with methods like `show(p, "aCertainPanel")`, `next()`, `previous()`.

See [**How to use CardLayout**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and see a simple runnable example [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435).

Also as Marco13 pointed out, avoid using null layouts and setting location and sizes manually. There many problems that arise with this. For your particular situation, it looks like `GridLayout` would be the perfect layout for you. See How to use `GridLayout` as well as others at [**Laying out Components Within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)