# How do I add and display a JLabel at runtime?

Tags: java, swing

I created frame with button and when it is pressed all content is removed and replaced by new one. But I can not display label, here is my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    getContentPane().removeAll();

    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
    jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel2.setText("Hello World!");
    jLabel2.setLocation(80, 80);
    jLabel2.setVisible(true);

    getContentPane().add(jLabel2);

    getContentPane().repaint();
    pack();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: try setLocation(0,0); - it might be out of view..

Comment: thanks :) but it is in parent's location coordinations, so I have already try it, but same problem.

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I would avoid absolute positioning like the plague and use layouts instead. Then you can tell the container it needs to update and have it position your label automatically, in the best location based on panel size, screen resolution, and other factors outside of your control.

Comment: thanks for layout advice. it helped me on my next move. THANK YOU VERY MUCH ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `repaint()` try `validate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to remove all and add new components, use a `CardLayout`, which will *"layer"* panels and let you navigate between them. See [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and you can see a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459718/how-do-i-switch-jpanels-inside-a-jframe/21460065#21460065)

You can also see how to use `CardLayout` with [Netbeans GUI Builder here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435)

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful. When I corrected previous problem, I had problem with layout, then I read your answer and used it :) thanks

Comment: If the answer helped you solve your problem, feel free to tick the check mark as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `validate()` instead of `repaint`. The rest of your source looks fine.

> The validate method is used to cause a container to lay out its subcomponents again. It should be invoked when this container's subcomponents are modified (added to or removed from the container, or layout-related information changed) after the container has been displayed.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked! I thought that repaint() is that correct method, but I was wrong. Thanks AGAIN! :)