# How to show a JFrame after another one closed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Let's say i have two forms such as `a.java` and `b.java`. There is a button inside `a.java` that creates a `b` object,hides itself and opens `b.java`. What i want is to show `a.java` again after i close `b.java`. Could anyone give me a simple example about this situation?

**EDIT:**
Let me give an example about my situation. I have a chart like this:
[image]

When i click one of the values, a new `pieChart` pops up, gives detailed information about the value. I can look any numbers of values with opening new JFrames. So, i think `JTabbedPane` can't solve my problem.

Comment: `setVisible()` is a handy method that works rather simply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect situation for a `CardLayout`, where panels will be *"layered"* and you can easily navigate through them using methods like `show()`, `previous()`, `next()`

See more at [**How to use CardLayout**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

You can also see a simple example [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435) and if you happen to be using Netbeans GUI Builder you can see how to use `CardLayout` with the diesign view [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435)

Also see [**The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/2587435). The popular answer is NO. `CardLayout` seems to fit the bill for your situation.

Comment: I believe he wants a new JFrame to be shown after another one has been closed.

Comment: @mig-25foxbat but he also said he want the other to appear back. This is more suited for `CardLayout`, than using multiple frames.

Comment: wokay, I removed my answer, the title of the question was quite misleading.

Comment: @peeskillet But what about the situation that i need to create more than one JFrame? I need to monitor more than one servers in my case.

Comment: Seems like a `JTabbedPane` might be suitable for that. `CardLayout` and `JTabbedPane` work very similar, just `JTabbedPane` has visible tabs to navigate and `CardLayout` you can create your own buttons to navigate.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark so when you open the new frame, it's all new data, is that what your saying? What about when you navigate back to the old frame, will that be new data too or still the old data?

Comment: it will be the old data.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark What's wrong with just using a modal `JDialog`? I guess I'm wondering why do you need to make the first frame not visible? If you use a modal `JDialog` only that dialog will be accessible until you close it.

Comment: You're right. I guess i need to make this problem more clear, with the links that you added. Will ask a new question with more specific situation about this.