# JFrame with Dynamic JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am doing a program and I need that a JFrame change their components according to one seleccion in a main JFrame, I tried to do so:

```
public void agregarPanelSegunPrueba(FrmBoleto frm)
{
    //this panel is a JPanel make with the graphical editor in netbeans
    PnlPruebaDCExesoVelocidad pnl = new PnlPruebaDCExesoVelocidad();
    pnl.repaint();
    pnl.revalidate();
    frm.getContentPane().remove(frm.getPnlPruebasDistanciaTiempo());
    frm.getContentPane().add(pnl);
    frm.pack();
    frm.setVisible(true);

}
```

somebody know which is wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead of adding an removing entire panels. You can see a simple example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435)

Comment: I want to make the JPanel with netbeans editor without cardlayout. thanks

Comment: It still looks like a good situation for a `CardLayout`. See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435) for how to use `CardLayout` in the design view of Netbeans GUI Builder.

Comment: you are right. I think that is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `revalidate();repaint();` not `JPanel` which you add,but just container to that you add your panel.

You need to call:

```
frm.getContentPane().revalidate();
frm.getContentPane().repaint();
```

instead of :

```
pnl.repaint();
pnl.revalidate();
```

after that line: `frm.getContentPane().add(pnl);`

Comment: does not work, but don't matter I going to use the cardlayout. thaks a lot

Comment: @Premier to call revalidate(); & repaint(); once time, as last code line, after all changes to Swing GUI are executed

Comment: @mKorbel seems that there other problem because `frm.pack();` solves revalidate problem

Comment: right [valid/only in the case that you don't want to change JFrames bounds, stays unchanged](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6989230/714968), and its contents can be schrinked

Answer (score 0):

```
public void agregarPanelSegunPrueba(FrmBoleto frm)
{
    //this panel is a JPanel make with the graphical editor in netbeans
    PnlPruebaDCExesoVelocidad pnl = new PnlPruebaDCExesoVelocidad();
    pnl.repaint();
    pnl.revalidate();
    frm.getContentPane().removeAll();
    frm.getContentPane().add(pnl);
    frm.pack();
    frm.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: everything is fine until it has add the panel, finally the JFrame show me an empty window.