# Swing table not rewriting

Tags: java, swing, object, reference

Main window class (extended `JFrame`, built with GUI editor) holds reference to `JTable` object (lets call it **table**). Which is empty `new JTable()` at beginning. And is added to `JPanel` (lets call it **jpanel1**), which is also in main window.

User now choose from menu what he want to do - like creating new table,editing colors in table etc..
If he choose ,that he want to create new table ,then particular extended `JPanel` (lets call it **customJPanel1**) is shown with options. **customJPanel1** receives reference to **table** from main window. This is table we are going to work with.

Now user has show different options for different constructors of `JTable` . He picks one and fills out some info ,then press button. 
After that according to what he has picked new `JTable` is created.

For example if he choose empty constructor ,the this happen:
  `table=new JTable()`
in customJPanel1. As you know you just can not do this to swing components while they are shown. So I do this:

```
JPanel panel=(JPanel) table.getParent().getParent().getParent() // this is to get reference to jPanel1 which is holding this table.
panel.removeAll()                         //this is to remove old table from panel
table=new JTable();  //this is to create new table according to what user choose
JScrollPane jScrollPane=new JScrollPane(table);
panel.add(jScrollPane);  // this is to add new table to panel
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

This part of code works good for first time and new Table is shown.
Now user select other option for example he wants to color table.
So in main window I do this:

```
customPanel1=new ColorPanel(table);
```

**customPanel1** should receive reference to **newly created table** object in this constructor ,but it does not. 
Main Window is still sending reference to **old table object**.

I would like to put here short part of codes , but I hope it will be easy to understand from my resume as my codes are little big bigger.

Comment: Try calling `panel.validate()` after the change is made.

Comment: Hey, I forgot to add that but I am calling panel.revalidate() and panel with table is shown. Problem is that main window still somehow holds reference to old table instead new. Also tried calling revalidate() on main window.

Comment: Have you tried `validate()`...`revalidate()` has never worked for me.  And when you say it's holding the old reference, do you mean it's displaying the old table (not the new one) or do you mean the actual object contains the old table and not the new one?

Comment: Its displaying new ,but contains reference to old.

Comment: You should hold a reference to 'jpanel1' instead of using getParent().getParent().getParent(). Additionally, it looks like you set the reference to panel using the panel's great-grand-parent but then insert it as a grand-child. Compare table > ? > ? > ? to panel > jscrollpane > table. You are depending on the implementation of JScrollPane to wrap the component-to-wrap within an intermediate wrapper. I don't think this behavior is in the specs.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 3):

So here's the deal. You don't want to keep creating new tables, removing the old one and adding the one. Completely unnecessary. What you want to do to change the table data, is swap `TableModels` *or* alter the existing one. You can see more at [Creating a TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg).

Try this as a simple test (instead of removing the old table and creating a new one), just change the data/model.

```
Object[] colNames = { "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3" };
Object[][] data = { { "Data", "Data", "Data" },
                    { "Data", "Data", "Data" },
                    { "Data", "Data", "Data" } };
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols);
table.setModel(model);
```

You should see the data change automatically.

---

As an aside, if you really do need to swap views, instead of trying to add an remove containers, you should look into using a `CardLayout` that let's you swap views without having to add and remove components (which can be troublesome). You can see more at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) an see a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435). Also you may also want to look at [How to Use CardLayout with Netbeans GUI Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435)

---

**UPDATE**

> "so I will have to clear every change user made to table in order to match changes what would do for example empty constructor ( new JTable() )"

You can do this with the model. Look at all the methods from [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) you can use. If you initialize your table with a `DefaultTableModel`

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

you can then use methods like

> `public void setColumnIdentifiers(Object[] newIdentifiers)` - To change the headers
>
> `public void setRowCount(int rowCount)` - set the number of rows. Use 0 to clear model.
>
> `public void addRow(Object[] rowData)` - to add rows dynamically.

And also many more methods. Look at the [`API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

Comment: If anything other helps I will go for this , but only problem is that this program should show users how tables works ,so I will have to clear every change user made to table in order to match changes what would do for example empty constructor ( new JTable() ) to this table. So somehow simulate creating new Table.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. I can tell you is that tables are _supposed_ to work with models. If you _really_ want to show how a table works, then you _should_ be showing something about the table model.

Comment: See my **UPDATE**. Maybe that will help.