# Java: Changing Panels during runtime

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

The following method has the end result I need. The problem is, when the method is called, the starting `pnlMain` stays visible until the new `pnlMain` is created and replaces the original.
The point of this method is to change the panel by creating a new one but this process takes a little time, so I am trying to have the "load" panel show up during that time.

```
public void changePanel() {
    remove(pnlMain);
    add(load);
    repaint();
    pnlMain = new HunterPanel(settings); // HunterPanel extends JPanel
    remove(load);
    add(pnlMain);
    repaint();
    pnlMain.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: Is your question how to add the load panel while the panel is changed?

Answer (score 3):

> "Changing Panels during runtime"

The correct way is to use a `CardLayout` that will allow you to switch between views. See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details. See a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435)

But just to let you know where you're going wrong in your code, if you remove and add components at runtime, you need to `revalidate()`. But in your case, go with the `CardLayout`. After you learn it, you be happy you did :-)