# JFrame crashes when trying to replace a panel with another panel

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame which is initialized as follows:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setPreferredSize(PREFERRED_SIZE);
setTitle("Game Set");

setLayout(new BorderLayout());
background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/gameSetBackground.jpg"));
background.setPreferredSize(PREFERRED_SIZE);
add(background);

loginPane = new LoginPane();

background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
loginPane.setOpaque(false);
background.add(loginPane, constraints);

pack();
setVisible(true);
```

I did it this way because it let me set the background to the jpg I specify. Now I have the loginPane() class as follows:

```
public class LoginPane extends JPanel {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Login");
    JLabel secondLabel = new JLabel("If you don't have a profile, click below to create one!");
    JTextField userName;
    JPasswordField password;

    public LoginPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        userName = new JTextField(20);
        password = new JPasswordField(20);

        constraints.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        add(label, constraints);

        // etc add all of them the same way

        constraints.gridy = 3;
        add(secondLabel, constraints);

        userName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                password.requestFocus();
            }
        });

        password.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (userName.getText().equals("Mike")) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is that when I hit enter after a username and password has been entered, I will check if that is a valid username/password pair. After that I want to remove everything here and display a different `JPanel`. Inside the password.ActionListener, I tried the following:

```
loginPane.removeAll();

background.removeAll();
```

Those were two separate cases, but both cause the JFrame to crash, the TextFields become unresponsive and I have to exit out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "JFrame crashes when trying to replace a panel with another panel"

Simple/and correct solution would be to use a `CardLayout` to switch between panels. See more at [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and see a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435).

The `CardLayout` has methods like `show()` to to show a certain panel by name, `next()` to show the next panel, and `previous()` to show the previous panel. This is preferred way, over removing and adding panels.