# Ad selected panel throw JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox

I'm having problem with adding another JPanel to my frame when I'm using combobox.
I want to change the center panel according to the selection in combobox.
I made differehnt panel to all selections but it didn't add to my main panel.
I added the code.

thanks :)

```
import AllClasses.FlightCompany;
{
public class WorkerDialog extends JFrame {
    private JPanel Worker;
    private String[] LabelNames = { "Worker Type:", " Worker Name:" };
    String [] str = { "Office", "Host",
    "Pilot" };
    JComboBox<String> ChooseBox = new JComboBox<>(str);
    public JPanel MainPanel;
    private JPanel [] p= new JPanel[3];

    public WorkerDialog(FlightCompany f) {
        super("Worker Dialog");

        p[0] = new Office_Gui();
        p[1] = new Host_Gui();
        p[2] = new Pilot_Gui();
        Worker = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
        JLabel LabelName = new JLabel(LabelNames[0]);
        JLabel LabelName2 = new JLabel(LabelNames[1]);
        JTextField fieldBox = new JTextField();
        LabelName.setSize(40, 25);
        ChooseBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 22));
        Worker.add(LabelName);
        Worker.add(ChooseBox);
        Worker.add(LabelName2);
        fieldBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 22));
        Worker.add(fieldBox);
        JPanel AddPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 1, 1));
        AddPanel.add(new JButton("Add"));
        AddPanel.add(new JButton("TakeOff"));
        MainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
        AddPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 110));
        ChooseBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {



            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //String str = e.getActionCommand();
                String jb =  (String) ChooseBox.getSelectedItem();
                if (jb.equals("Office")){

                    MainPanel.add(p[0],BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    System.out.println("Office");}
            }
        });








        MainPanel.add(Worker, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        MainPanel.add(AddPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(MainPanel);
        //pack();
        setSize(560, 300);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use a `CardLayout` for your `mainPanel`, that will allow you to easily switch between panels. Then add all your panels to the `mainPanel`, specifying a name for the panel. That name will go in the combo box. When you want to show a certain panel, just call `cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "nameOfPanel")`

To learn more about `Cardlayout` see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). You can also see a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435)

An aside: Use Java naming convention. Variables begin with lower case letters, using camel casing. ie:

- `ChooseBox` → `chooseBox`
- `MainPanel` → `mainPanel`
- etc.