# Java swing timer for GUI applicaton

Tags: java, swing, timer

Here is the following code, which I would like to use:

```
    private int counter = 1000;
    private int delay = 1000;
    private Timer timer;

        ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            jLabel19.setText("452");
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer(delay, action);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    timer.start();
```

It should pause the running, but it makes seemly nothing.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "pause the running" ?

Comment: Why give you negative, if you also can not solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> "It should pause the running, but it makes seemly nothing."

1. You set the initial delay to 0, so there's no delay
2. You have `jLabel19.setText("452");` called every tick. What change do you expect with a hard coded value?

---

Maybe you want to decrease the counter and set the text to the counter.

```
private int counter = 1000;
private int delay = 1000;
private Timer timer;

ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {   
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (counter == 0) {
            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
        } else {
            counter--;
            jLabel19.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        }
    }
};

timer = new Timer(delay, action);
timer.setInitialDelay(0);
timer.start();
```

Comment: I would like to count down, than I would like to change automatically the jFrame.

Comment: Change _what_ in the frame? And count down from _what_? You question is not clear as to your requirements, that's why you are getting down voted.

Comment: After the `((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();` You can do whatever you want with the frame. Also note, the counter will count for 1000 seconds, which is a pretty long time. Maybe you'll want to change that.

Comment: peeskillet : Change the frame=Change the whole frame to another frame.

Comment: Don't use multiple frames. Use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: But CardLayout also should be changed sometimes. Or not?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. One panel has a CardLayout. You add multiple panels the _that_ panel. Only one panel is shown. You use the Cardlayout to switch the panel shown in the main panel. See example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435).

Comment: Sorry, panels, but also these panels should be changed.

Comment: Yes. You can change the panel just by calling `cardlayout.show(..)`. See the example and read the tutorial

Comment: Okay, I can implement this, it works.
But the timer is not working. I have paste the declarations to the init state and the other codes to a function.

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly the purpose of the timer is, and what it should do.

Comment: If you post your code, maybe I can help you further