# How to change the frame of the same window in java GUI?

Tags: java

I'm making a game and whenever I press the play button the game should start in a new window. How to change the frame of the same window in Java GUI? How can I make the whole thing in one window?

Comment: Explain better what you want to do. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "so how can make the whole thing in one window"

See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). It will let you swap between views/panels, so you can stick to just one frame. Also see a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435)